# Parse HHMMSS.nano correctly in Dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, datetime, datetime-format, python-datetime

|  | Time | right |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 122241.000000 | Three |
| 2 | 122242.003906 | Three |
| 3 | 122243.001532 | Three |
| 4 | 122244.008520 | Three |

I would like to convert the time using datetime, given that the actual format is
HHMMSS.nano

for example I tried :

```
datetime.strptime('122241.082031','%H%M%S.%f').time()
```

output  :

```
datetime.time(12, 22, 41, 82031)
```

In order to get the correct time but now how am I supposed to display this correct time into the dataframe column ?

Comment: It would be like this : 21:22:00.234360, the answer below fits perfectly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is that what you're looking for?

```
df['tm']=pd.to_datetime(df['Time'], unit='m').dt.time
df
```

```
    Time            right   tm
1   122241.000000   Three   21:21:00
2   122242.003906   Three   21:22:00.234360
3   122243.001532   Three   21:23:00.091920
4   122244.008520   Three   21:24:00.511200
```